# Proliant Server E200i Raid Controller does not see array

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, raid5, hp-smart-array

Help!  My server was configured with 3 arrays:  array 1 and 2 were each 136Gb raid 5  using the first 5 drives.  3 x 72Gb and 2 x 300Gb. Array 3 was 3 x 500Gb using drives 6 7 8 for 1Tb.

I had a failing 300Gb  and it was decided to remove array 1 and 2 and the three 72Gb and the failing 300Gb and add 2 more 300Gb in a raid 5 array of 600gb.   I imaged arrays 1 and 2 to an external drive.  Rebooted and removed array 1 and 2 in the controller BIOS.  shut down and removed drives 1,2,3 (72Gb) and installed the 300Gb drives. At no time did I delete the 3 x 500Gb Array but the array is now gone!  It shows the three drives as unassigned. I dare not tell the controller to re-raid because it will toast the data on the drives.  The lights on the 3 500's are out.  The other installed drives are green.  The array BIOS is 1.66 and I hope to update it to 1.86C tomorrow.  Anyone have advice on how to recover the data/raid configuration?  The backups are online and it will take weeks to download it all.

Answer (score 0):

- If you insert the drives in the same order
- If you re-create the array (raid) with the same parameters (raid5)

There is **some chance** that you can regain your data. I would do this as a last resort. If you or anyone have better idea you can try that before.

I would not upgrade the controller's BIOS now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was a strange sequence of actions...

- Which array did the server actually boot from prior to your changes? Presumably the first logical drive?
- Did you expect to be able to *boot* the server again after deleting that first logical drive?
- Why did you choose to delete logical drives because of a failed disk?

Furthermore, doing all of this from the old BIOS utility is silly. More complex array configuration work should take place using the Smart Start CD or the [**Array Configuration Utility Offline disk**](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=428936&swItem=MTX-3c888073127c4c65b7bd8559eb&prodNameId=3288114&swEnvOID=4022&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=3).

I think you conflated "array" and "logical drive", and probably deleted the *array* comprised of the 500GB disks. The BIOS utility can't actually manage complex logical drive configurations.

Did you mean that you had an array comprised of *five* drives (3x72GB and 2x300GB) with two logical drives configured on top of size 136GB? If that's true, you inadvertently deleted both arrays.

Try booting the server with the offline disk (or .ISO). Remember, HP arrays store the array metadata on the disks, not the controller. So if your data is still intact, that would be the best approach to see it.